# Why does my variable not change after `var++`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

All I want is my variable `huidige` to go up, and `foto` to change as well. What have I done wrong?

```
var huidige = 1;
var foto = 'url(img/foto' + huidige + '.jpg)';

setInterval(function() {
  huidige++;

  if (huidige == 4) {
    huidige = 1;
  }

  $('.background_img').css('backgroundImage', foto);
}, 300);
```

Comment: `foto` does not update when `huidige` is reassigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update `foto` after you update `huidige`:

```
var huidige = 1;

setInterval(function() {
  huidige++;

  if (huidige == 4) {
    huidige = 1;
  }

  $('.background_img').css('backgroundImage', 'url(img/foto' + huidige + '.jpg');
}, 300);
```

Comment: Or eliminate the use of `foto`entirely and just interpolate `huidige`.

Comment: Yes @Li357 I'll edit my answer, thanks for pointing that out.